# MVC 4.5 Web API request is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api

I have designed a MVC 4.5 Web API in .Net.  HTTP request has to be made from Jquery AJAX Call.
After making the call(POST) I get the following error in console. Can anyone help me to identify what I am doing wrong?

```
    OPTIONS http://192.168.xx.xx:1245/api/values 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
OPTIONS http://192.168.xx.xx:1245/api/values Invalid HTTP status code 405 jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.xx.xx:1245/api/values. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the [`same origin policy restriction`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) by making a cross domain AJAX call which is not allowed by default. You might need to enable CORS on the Web API side: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -project YourWebApiProject
```

and then in your config simply enable CORS:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This will enable you to make cross domain AJAX requests to your Web API from browsers that support CORS.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a whole day fixing this issue in my API.

Here is what i did to overwrite the OPTION method in the API

You have to set this in your web.cnofig inside system.webservers

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Authorization, Data, Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Then in your WebApiConfig.cs put this code

```
public class OptionsHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                return resp;
            });
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And register that with this line in the Register function in the same WebApiConfig.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new OptionsHttpMessageHandler());
```

Comment: Started from morning and finally this solved my problem, I was almost going to have api-2 before this.. Thanks alot