# OPTIONS Request occassionally pending forever when requesting API

Tags: javascript, c#, request, fetch

at the moment I am having a problem with a GET request to an API endpoint.
On very rare occasions, the OPTIONS request is shown as pending (in Google Chrome) forever, so the GET request does not get performed. In 99% of the requests, everything works just fine, but sometimes it does not.

Here is what I do:

I try to call the following C# API endpoint via GET:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("qr/{QrCode}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetByQr(string QrCode)
{
    return Ok(DeserializeQrCode(QrCode)); // this is simplified...
}
```

To do this, I use the fetch method:

```
fetch('<baseUrl>/qr/<qrCode>', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    }
})
.then(console.log.bind(console))
.catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Usually, I would see the OPTIONS request, followed by the GET request, returning the desired value. However, as already stated, sometimes the OPTIONS request is pending forever.

In Visual Studio 2015 (which I use for debugging), I can see the options request, but nothing further.

Any ideas on what could be going on there? Why does an OPTIONS request keep pending?

Thank you very much!
Rico

Edit: this is a .NET 4.5.2 WebApi project.

Comment: Please also add the code responsible for the adding of CORS headers plus the section in which the options verb is set to always go through by the server

Comment: CORS is enabled by app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
But I did not modify the OPTIONS verb AFAIK anywhere.

Comment: I found this very similar post which goes through the config for 4.5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796249/mvc-4-5-web-api-request-is-not-working

Comment: Perhaps just run through it to make sure you haven't missed anything